# How to fix 'jnius.jnius.JavaException' in kivy plyer vibrate android test apk (with buildozer compilation)

Tags: android, kivy, pyjnius

I wan't test plyer library with kivy and i tried to test a simple android vibrate.
The app end with this log  :

```
04-17 23:49:40.292 15287 15340 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1034, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
04-17 23:49:40.292 15287 15340 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: No methods matching your arguments, available: [u'(ILjava/lang/String;[JILandroid/media/AudioAttributes;)V', u'(ILjava/lang/String;JLandroid/media/AudioAttributes;)V']
04-17 23:49:40.292 15287 15340 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

It's a simple Kivy plyer vibrate test

Ubuntu 18.04 - Kivy v1.10.1 - Python v2.7.15rc1 - plyer-1.4.0 - Buildozer 0.39 - cython-0.29.7 - pyjnius-1.2.0

```py
__version__ = '1.0'

import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from plyer import vibrator

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout()
        btn = Button(text='Vibrate')
        bl.add_widget(btn)
        btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        return bl

    def callback(instance, value):
        vibrator.vibrate(10)
```

buildozer.spec

```
requirements = kivy, python2
android.permissions = VIBRATE
```

I expect a simple android phone vibrate to test

Comment: Add `plyer` into `requirements`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I get the same error message...

Comment: Looks like possibly a bug in plyer. Does using pjnius directly work, e.g. as described [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Pyjnius-Vibrator-Example)?

Comment: I still get the same error message...